# Switch Cases in React Native

Tags: react-native, if-statement, switch-statement

Hi all I am trying to use a switch case to update text after a user selects it from a list. I'm not super familiar with react native so am unsure if I am missing something easy. I appreciate any help/feedback. Please let me know if I can provide any extra information. Thanks!

```
        <ProfilePropertyInfoCompact
          style={{ marginBottom: 17 }}
          fieldName={translations['edituserprofile.size']}
          value={userSize ? userSize : translations['unknown']}
          onPress={() => {
            setModalData({
              options: [
                translations['xx-small.weight'],
                translations['x-small.weight'],
                translations['small.weight'],
                translations['medium.weight'],
                translations['large.weight'],
                translations['x-large.weight'],
                translations['xx-large.weight'],
                translations['xxx-large.weight'],
              ],
              fieldName: translations['edituserprofile.size'],
              modalTitle: translations['edituserprofile.size'],
              selected: userSize,
              onModalSelect: (item) => {
                switch (item) {
                  case translations['xx-small.weight']:
                    return translations['xx-small'];
                  case translations['x-small.weight']:
                    return translations['x-small'];
                  case translations['small.weight']:
                    return translations['small'];
                  case translations['medium.weight']:
                    return translations['medium'];
                  case translations['lalrge.weight']:
                    return translations['large'];
                  case translations['x-large.weight']:
                    return translations['x-large'];
                  case translations['xx-large.weight']:
                    return translations['xx-large'];
                  case translations['xxx-large.weight']:
                    return translations['xxx-large'];
                  default:
                    '';
                }
                setuserSize(item);
                setIsModalOpen(false);
              },
            });
            setIsModalOpen(true);
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the switch statement was stopping the item from being set by `setuserSize`. To get around this I created a function and made `item` equal to the function and passed in `item`.

```
const sizeTranslationMap = (weightRange) => {
    switch (weightRange) {
      case translations['xx-smallweight']:
        return translations['xx-small'];
      case translations['x-smallweight']:
        return translations['x-small'];
      case translations['smallweight']:
        return translations['small'];
      case translations['mediumweight']:
        return translations['medium'];
      case translations['largeweight']:
        return translations['large'];
      case translations['x-largeweight']:
        return translations['x-large'];
      case translations['xx-largeweight']:
        return translations['xx-large'];
      case translations['xxx-largeweight']:
        return translations['xxx-large'];
      default:
        return '';
    }
  };
```

```
onModalSelect: (item) => {
                item = sizeTranslationMap(item);
                setuserSize(item);
                setIsModalOpen(false);
              },
```